# SAP BO SDK calls taking time

Tags: java, business-objects

I am trying to generate meta data like number of universes , folders , users , user groups , permissions etc using SAP Business Objects  Java SDK  but the SDK calls are taking significant time .  Just a 3000+ records are taking more than 2 hrs of time..   Upon debugging I figured out the  BO SDK calls like  infoStore queries  using query builders are really slow.

I understood that infoStore queries  from  `CI_SYSTEMOBJECTS` ,  `CI_APPOBJECTS` , `CI_INFOOBJECTS` are the only way to fetch the metadata  from SAP BO  , is there any other alternative ?

Anyone faced this issue and got a better and faster solution  to get the metadata from the repository?

Comment: coding is missing, bro. god knows how you do it

Answer (score 1):

Those queries can take time, depending on the properties requested (in SELECT), and the conditions applied (in WHERE).  If you can modify the query statement so that it's only retrieving the properties and objects that are required for your program, you will optimize the runtime.

Note that you can test CMS queries interactively via query builder: http://:8080/AdminTools.

If you want to update your question with the specific query that's taking time, I can see if I can offer any advice.